# Create Virtual Graph Virtuoso

Tags: graph, virtuoso

On my knowledge base deployed on [Virtuoso v7.2.1](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), I've two RDF graphs, namely `http://example.com/A` and `http://example.com/B`, populated by triples.

I'd like to create a virtual graph `http://example.com/VG` that should represent the union of `http://example.com/A` and `http://example.com/B`. 
Therefore, any change on either `http://example.com/A` and `http://example.com/B` should be propagated to `http://example.com/VG`.

Digging into the documentation I did not find pointers and the closest thing to do, the so-called [RDF View](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration), operates on tables and not RDF graphs. 
Has anyone a suggestion on how to implement it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Virtuoso way to do this is a [Graph Group](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFGraphsSecurity#RDF%20Graph%20Groups).

You'll need to use [`DB.DBA.RDF_GRAPH_GROUP_CREATE()`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_rdf_graph_group_create.html), [`DB.DBA.RDF_GRAPH_GROUP_INS()`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_rdf_graph_group_ins.html), and related functions.

The Graph Group is effectively a `VIEW` of of a `UNION` of its Member Graphs, so changes to the Member Graphs are immediately reflected through the Graph Group.  There is no change propagation, as such.

For future -- Virtuoso-specific questions often get faster response from on the [Virtuoso users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), [OpenLink support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), etc.